# Spark: Filter based on multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have two datasets as below and would like to filter dataset1(ds1) based on the column values in dataset2(ds2).
That is, I need to filter dataset1 based on the combination of key(ID,NAME,ACCID,CURR) and the AMT value should be ZERO in dataset2.

```
val ds1 = Seq(
    ("T1001","WELLINGTON","991","CAD",150),("T1002","WELLINGTON","8787","CAD",1450),("T1002","WELLINGTON","8787","YEN",3000),
    ("T1002","WELLINGTON","8787","USD",500),("T1003","WELLINGTON","654","USD",200),("T1003","WELLINGTON","654","INR",3500),
    ("T1003","WELLINGTON","654","YEN",3500),("T1004","WELLINGTON","7567","YEN",9765),("T1005","WELLINGTON","1456","AUD",8888),
    ("T1005","WELLINGTON","1456","GBP",666),("T1005","WELLINGTON","1456","YEN",5500)
).toDF("ID","NAME","ACCID","CURR","AMT")

+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
|   ID|      NAME|ACCID|CURR| AMT|
+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
|T1001|WELLINGTON|  991| CAD| 150|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| CAD|1450|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| YEN|3000|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| USD| 500|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| USD| 200|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| INR|3500|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| YEN|3500|
|T1004|WELLINGTON| 7567| YEN|9765|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| AUD|8888|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| GBP| 666|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| YEN|5500|
+-----+----------+-----+----+----+

val ds2 = Seq(
    ("T1001","WELLINGTON","991","CAD",150),("T1002","WELLINGTON","8787","CAD",1450),("T1002","WELLINGTON","8787","YEN",0),
    ("T1002","WELLINGTON","8787","USD",500),("T1003","WELLINGTON","654","USD",200),("T1003","WELLINGTON","654","GBP",0),
    ("T1003","WELLINGTON","654","YEN",0),("T1004","WELLINGTON","7567","YEN",0),("T1005","WELLINGTON","1456","AUD",8888),
    ("T1005","WELLINGTON","1456","GBP",666),("T1005","WELLINGTON","1456","YEN",0)
).toDF("ID","NAME","ACCID","CURR","AMT")

+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
|   ID|      NAME|ACCID|CURR| AMT|
+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
|T1001|WELLINGTON|  991| CAD| 150|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| CAD|1450|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| YEN|   0|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| USD| 500|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| USD| 200|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| GBP|   0|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| YEN|   0|
|T1004|WELLINGTON| 7567| YEN|   0|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| AUD|8888|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| GBP| 666|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| YEN|   0|
+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
```

I was trying to do with JOIN and FILTER but would like to know if there is any other better way of doing this
as I need to only filter few thousand records. 
ZERO records on the dataset2 could be small (like ~5000 rows or less) and dataset1 rows could be in millions.

```
ds1.join(ds2, Seq("ID","NAME","ACCID","CURR"), "leftouter")
.select(ds1("ID"),ds1("NAME"),ds1("ACCID"),ds1("CURR"),ds1("AMT"),ds2("AMT").name("AMT2"))
.filter(expr("NVL(AMT2,-99) != 0")).drop("AMT2")
.show()

+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
|   ID|      NAME|ACCID|CURR| AMT|
+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
|T1001|WELLINGTON|  991| CAD| 150|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| CAD|1450|
|T1002|WELLINGTON| 8787| USD| 500|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| USD| 200|
|T1003|WELLINGTON|  654| INR|3500|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| AUD|8888|
|T1005|WELLINGTON| 1456| GBP| 666|
+-----+----------+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: If you haven't applied filter to ds2 before, Spark should be able to know that it's small. This means the join algorithm will use a broadcast hash join, which should be fast. You can check it using the `dataframe.explain` method.

Comment: the filter predicate will be pushed down as much as possible

Comment: Hi @Miguel, yes I test it and its using ***BroadcastHashJoin***    

 +- *Filter (coalesce(AMT2#2244, -99) != 0)
    +- *BroadcastHashJoin [ID#983, NAME#975, ACCID#976, 
          coalesce(CURR#980, )] ....